# How to give title to a radiobutton through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I ama trying to give a title to a radio button through as it is creating dynamically how can it possible

here is my code

```
var i = 3; 
function textAreaCreate(){

var l = document.createElement("label");
l.innerHTML = "Option " + i;
document.getElementById("myForm").appendChild(l);

var r = document.createElement("input");
r.innerHTML = "Option " + i;
r.setAttribute("type", "radio");
r.setAttribute("Name", "CorrectAns");
document.getElementById("coreectOpt").appendChild(r);

i++;

}
```

And html code

```
<div  id="coreectOpt"> //For radio button
</div>

<div class="form-group"  id="myForm"> //For label                                
</div>
 <a href="#" class="textAreaCreate" onclick="textAreaCreate()">Add More Options</a>
```

Label is working successfully but radio button is not [image]

i want C, D and so on,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, the text you're assigning is just `Option` concatenated with a number. If you want to use letters instead, you could use `fromCharCode` to convert the number to a letter.

Also, to have the radio button clicked when the label is clicked, assign a unique string to the `label`'s `for` attribute, and give the radio button the same `id`.

Also note that radio buttons don't have `innerHTML` properties - don't try to assign to them.

```js
let i = 3;
function textAreaCreate() {
  const letter = String.fromCharCode(i + 62);
  const labelString = "Option " + letter;
  const l = document.createElement("label");
  // Starts at character code 62, which is "A":
  l.textContent = labelString;
  l.setAttribute('for', letter);
  document.getElementById("myForm").appendChild(l);

  const r = document.createElement("input");
  r.id = letter;
  r.setAttribute("type", "radio");
  r.setAttribute("Name", "CorrectAns");
  document.getElementById("coreectOpt").appendChild(r);
  i++;
}
```

```html
<div id="coreectOpt">
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="myForm">
</div>
<a href="#" class="textAreaCreate" onclick="textAreaCreate()">Add More Options</a>
```